# How to use EnvInject Jenkins plugin correctly?

Tags: jenkins

Work flow I want to create

1. 'Shell Executors' write variables to `build.properties` file.
2. EnvInject plugin reads `build.properties` injects them as environment variable, so it possible to use them everywhere in the job. 
   [image: job config]

I got such exception instead:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on master-worker (lucid) in workspace /data/jenkins/workspace/QA-350_MultiJob
[QA-350_MultiJob] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson757569632298940894.sh
+ curl --user **** -X POST --header Content-Type: application/json --header Accept: */* -d {
  "description": "string",
  "mode": "DEFAULT",
  "name": "string",
  "start_time": "2015-11-05T13:26:40.626Z",
  "tags": [
    "string"
  ]
} https://****
+ jq .id
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0   144      0    286 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   286
  0    33    0    33    0   144     49    215 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
+ ID = "563c8d3ae4b0bf061cd3d999"
/tmp/hudson757569632298940894.sh: 1: ID: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: While @freebourn has good suggestions, the actual error shows that `ID = $(...)` is failing because in the shell, there should not be spaces in an assignment: `ID=$(...)`

Comment: Next time, please give us the code that is failing (not an image of it, with some key details blacked out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to add anything in "Properties Content", as long as the file you are pointing to in "Properties File Path" contains variable assignments (e.g. ID = 123).

- Verify the file in workspace created by your shell script contains your variable assignment.
- Clear "Properties Content" box.
- You may remove $WORKSPACE from the "Properties File Path" - its is relative to your job's workspace by default.

You should than have the variable from the file loaded to the job's environment.

Answer (score 5):

Came across this and was having a VERY similar problem..

Same error message informing me that the variable name I was trying create was not found (notice for this question are trying to create a variable named ID and the error is telling us that 'ID is not found')

If you remove the spaces around 'ID = ${curl ' it should resolve the issue.

**Variable creation in shell scripts requires no spaces to be used.
Example: MY_VARIABLE="my value"**